# Mixed boundary condition of parabolic equations

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, elliptic-pde, parabolic-pde, linear-pde

Let $ \Omega $ be a bounded and smooth domain in $ \mathbb{R}^n $. Assume that
$$
\partial\Omega=\partial\Omega_D\cup\partial\Omega_N,
$$
where $ \partial\Omega_D $ and $ \partial\Omega_N $ are nonempty smooth and connected. Consider the initial boundary problem as follows.
$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
&\partial_tu-\Delta u=F&\text{ in }&\Omega\times(0,T),\\
&u(x,0)=u_0(x)&\text{ on }&\Omega\times\{0\},\\
&u(x,t)=0&\text{ on }&\partial\Omega_D\times(0,T),\\
&\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}(x,t)=0&\text{ on }&\partial\Omega_N\times(0,T),
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
where $ \nu $ is the outer unit normal vector of $ \partial\Omega $ and $ F\in L^p(\Omega\times(0,T)) $. The above model is of mixed boundary conditions. I wonder if I can get the regularity estimates for $ u $. Can you give me some hints or references?